# Query with "the" not returning results

Tags: apache, apigee, usergrid, apigee-baas

I'm trying to select an entity with "The" as the first word of the **title** attribute but Usergrid seems to be ignoring it.

For example, this query which is attempting to select "The Giver"

```
/books?ql=select * where title contains 'the*' //returns no results
/books?ql=select * where title contains 'giver*' //returns "The Giver"
```

Is this be design?  Why is "the" ignored?  Is it some kind of keyword?  How could I work around this apparent limitation?

Answer (score 1):

This does not work in version 1.0 of Usergrid (the free tier of Apigee's API BaaS runs 1.0). It is, however, fixed in newer 2.X versions of the Usergrid project. I spent some time digging through for the relevant commit, but couldn't find it.